# How to get (needs included) controllers from a template in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller that proxies up a parent controllers model so I can ask if a property is undefined or not.

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: "todos",
    isLoaded: function() {
        return this.get("controllers.todos.model.isLoaded");
    }.property("controllers.todos.model.isLoaded")
});
```

I'd *much prefer* to pull this in a template directly but when I do the following my tests hang as it doesn't appear to be legit syntax

```
{{if controllers.todos.model.isLoaded}}
{{/if}}
```

Yet I know (in ember 1.11) you can still use controller (singular)

```
{{#if controller.content}}
{{/if}}
```

Is it possible to shorthand this computed or even include this in a template? If nothing else I could create a hbs helper (assuming I can get controllers from that scope).

Comment: Have you considered ensuring the  `todos.model` model is always loaded by returning a promise for that model, in the route's `beforeModel` or `afterModel` hooks? That way you need not have any code either in the template/controller that explicitly checks for `isLoaded`.

Comment: I'm actually avoiding the promise so I can paint faster on purpose :) The trick is to know when the xhr has resolved so my template can switch to showing content instead of a loading like placeholder

Comment: You are missing a #. It is {{#if ...}}

Comment: You mentioned your tests hang. Please post the test(s) that hang. You may be missing a needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background (that you probably already know): By default it looks like the template gets the controller as it's context, so you need to set a property on that controller to get it into the template.

Did some research and came across [this syntax](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/controller.js) in the code (also [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_controller) in the docs). I haven't seen anyone really talk about it though and I haven't used it yet myself so I don't know if the below actually works >_<. It's basically the same thing you're doing, but a little tighter:

```
todos: Ember.inject.controller()
```

then in the template:

```
{{#if todos.model.isLoaded}}
```

Comment: Thinking about it more, I don't know why controllers you specify with `needs` are not available in the context provided to the template.